# Using C# to light up an LED button on a Novation Launchpad Mini MK3

Tags: c#, lighting, led, launchpad

I wanted to make a simple program that will play an animation I can make to make my setup look nicer :) The thing I'm really struggling with is finding a solution for lighting up an LED on my Launchpad Mini MK3 by the X and Y coordinate or index.

I've tried DryWetMidi, but from reading the documentation I assume there are no lighting effects for it.

I thought about just sending some data straight to my launchpad, but I've never really worked with an external device, so I have no idea on how to make it.

If anyone has an idea, or a working **AND TRUSTED** library, it would be great if you mention it! Code examples are welcome!

Comment: Q: Can't you just download the  Novation driver (https://downloads.novationmusic.com/novation/launchpad-mk3/launchpad-mini-mk3-0) and control it with a standard C# USB library, (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/customusbdeviceaccess/)?

Comment: I didnt try it and didnt know that exists. I already had the Novation driver installed. Gimme some time to get any understanding about the USB library, and I will reply/update the post.

Comment: @paulsm4 from what I read, this library is intended to be used in an UWP application, and mine is a regular .NET console application, so that approach wouldnt quite work out. Is there any other way like using the Windows API to make a launchpad LED light up?

Comment: Even though it's documented as "UWP", I believe [Windows.Devices.Usb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.usb.usbdevice) is just a .NET assembly which you can integrate with any .NET project.  Q: Did you try it?